# Pandoc conversion from LaTeX+BibLaTeX to Markdown

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc, pandoc-citeproc

This should be relatively simple but I can't find a clear answer about how to do it.

I am using the command:

```
pandoc -s myfile.tex -o outfile.md --bibliography mybib.bib
```

But outfile.md does not end up having any bibliography.  What is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`citations` extension](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-citations) is on by default. Pandoc tries to produce the cleanest output possible, so it uses `@citeid` syntax instead of adding full citations when that extension is enabled. Disabling it will to the trick:

```
pandoc -t markdown-citations -s myfile.tex -o outfile.md --bibliography mybib.bib
```

Comment: Thanks!  This worked, but why don't I see `markdown-citations` as a possible FORMAT in the documentation, and why doesn't the section you linked to mention this syntax?

Comment: Different formats support different extensions. You can run `pandoc --list-extensions=markdown` to see the list of extensions supported in Markdown. Those extensions prefixed with `-` are disabled, those with `+` are enabled. So to autolink bare URIs while disabling citations, one would write `-t markdown+autolinks_bar_uris-citations`. See also https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extensions